# sed to replace lines matched by a pattern range if one line match a condition

Tags: python, regex, linux, sed, scripting

I need to delete record in the following sample file format:

```
record {
    record {
        my_id_1
        my_name_1
    }
    
    record {
        my_id_2
        my_name_2
    }
    
    record {
        my_id_3
        my_name_3
    }
}
```

We need to remove all record data using the unique value `my_id` or `my_id_2` in this case and expected result should be:

```
record {
    record {
        my_id_1
        my_name_1
    }
    
    record {
        my_id_3
        my_name_3
    }
}
```

Note: the file is not a standard talking about spaces, new lines, etc. But the core logic may be deleting everything between the word `record` [including the same word] that is only related to the `my_id_*` string in to the brackets.

All I've been able to do so far is write:

```
sed -n '/record/{:a;N;/}/!ba; /my_id_2/p}' file.conf
```

that, in fact, finds what I need but I'm not able to delete it I'm only printing the lines I want to clear.

`sed` is my primary option but also `python` `regex` may be fine so I can pass it to ansible.

##########################

THIS IS ALSO MY PYTHON TRY

##########################

TOOL: https://pythex.org/

using python this was the closest I got:

first try:
`(?=my_id_2)([^}]+)(?=\})`

with match result:

```
    `my_id_2 my_name_2`
```

then modified a bit:
`(?=record )([^}]+)(?=\})`

with match result:

`Match 1`

```
    `1. record { record { my_id_1 my_name_1`
```

`Match 2`

```
    `1. record { my_id_2 my_name_2`
```

`Match 3`

```
`1. record { my_id_3 my_name_3`
```

Thanks.

Comment: using python this was the closest I got:


first try:
 `(?=my_id_2)([^}]+)(?=\})`
 
with match result:
 `my_id_2 my_name_2`
   
then modified a bit:
 `(?=record )([^}]+)(?=\})`
 
with match result:
 `Match 1`
  `1. record { record { my_id_1 my_name_1`
 `Match 2`
  `1. record { my_id_2 my_name_2`
 `Match 3`
  `1. record { my_id_3 my_name_3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```sh
$ sed -i.bak '/record/{:a;N;/}/!ba; /my_id_2/d}' file.conf
$ cat file.conf
record {
    record {
        my_id_1
        my_name_1
    }
    
    
    record {
        my_id_3
        my_name_3
    }
}
```

The above modifies the file in-place and creates a backup of the file, named `file.conf.bak`. If you do not need a backup of the original file, you can remove `.bak` from `-i.bak`.

Answer (score 0):

Believe this does what you seek, but it prepends a blank line.  It's just bracketing them as paragraphs, then removing the one with that record name.

```
sed '/./{H;$!d} ;x; /my_id_2/d' file.conf
```

---

You'd think you could simply remove it with an extra `; 1d` appended to your sed statement.

```
sed '/./{H;$!d} ;x; /my_id_2/d ; 1d' file.conf
```

However, that has no effect, and line 1 is still blank.  You can overcome this, by piping it to a subsequent `sed` command, but that seems wonky.  Maybe someone else knows why.

```
sed '/./{H;$!d} ;x; /my_id_2/d' file.conf | sed '1d'
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/record \{/{:a;N;/\}/!ba;/my_id_2/!b;s/(record \{.*)\1.*/\1/;t;d}' file
```

Use your original approach but have an additional test using greed, which if it succeeds retains the front of the matching strings. If there is no such match, revert and as before delete the entire matching string.

N.B. This may introduce some unwanted padding the removal of which is left as an exercise for the reader ;-)